# What does "injection proxy" mean in RCS of HackingTeam?

Tags: proxy, injection

While I was watching [HT RCS Galileo Presentation](https://youtu.be/HcfuIwQOqoQ?t=547) I came across a term or concept which I'm not familiar with it: "*injection proxy*".

Could somebody explain this type of attack?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An **injection proxy** is a man-in-the-middle application that actively monitors traffic and injects (malicious) content based on predefined rules.

This is roughly the attack scenario outlined in the video:

You are a government entity and accessing the traffic of an ISP that you know is used by a criminal suspect A. You want to gain access to A's computer but you only have their e-mail address. So you set up a rule in the interface of your injection proxy that injects malware (possibly delivered through a 0-day browser exploit) into the traffic handled by the ISP as soon as A's e-mail address occurs in a HTTP request to their webmail provider. That is, as soon as A logs in on their webmail, your injection proxy takes action and injects malicious content into the returned HTTP response which silently installs a backdoor on their machine. This of course won't work as easily if A uses TLS when browsing since you can't easily inject content into HTTPS traffic.

A paper on details about HackingTeam's "Injection Proxy Appliance" can also be [found on Wikileaks](https://wikileaks.org/hackingteam/emails/fileid/595666/274112):

> IPA (Injection proxy appliance) is a offensive security device developed by HT for
>   performing remote installation of Remote Control System, by using man in the middle attack techniques and by using proprietary streamline injection mechanism.